# Can't forward e-mail with .procmail rc

Tags: postfix

I set up following .procmailrc

```
MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
:0 c
* ! ^X-Loop: user@hoge.jp
! forward@forward.com
```

but, I can't forward e-mails

Answer (score 1):

Did you tell postfix to use procmail??  I have the following in my '~/.forward':

```
"|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75 #user"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set something like:
    LOGFILE=/home/you/procmail.log

and see what shows up.  Paste it in here, and we'll be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

- why the c after :0 ? delete it
- Knows your MTA something about
  procmail? under exim4 there is a
  procmail router...
- if not, use also a .forward with something like that:

  ```
  "|IFS=' ' && exec /usr/local/bin/procmail || exit 75 #your_user_name"
  ```
- whats with a logfile in your .procmailrc?

  ```
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
  MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir/
  DEFAULT=$MAILDIR
  LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
  ```

Comment: The c after :O means to do this rule to a copy of the message.  I assume the intent is to send a copy along and still receive the message.

Comment: yes, I think so too, but there is an nother rule missing behind. _Perhaps_ this is the problem...

Comment: It will fall through and deliver as normal.  That's reasonable.